# Why does my light text have a strong anti-alias

Tags: css, font-face

I am having some display weirdness with @font-face fonts.

If the font is coloured white or a light colour like yellow, it appears to have strong anti-alias applied to it, something I don't appear to be able to control, is it just my eyes?

font declaration

Full @font-face

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lobster1.4';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('fonts/Lobster-1.4/Lobster-1.4.eot') format('eot');
    src: url('fonts/Lobster-1.4/Lobster-1.4.eot?#ieFix') format('eot'),
         url('fonts/Lobster-1.4/Lobster-1.4.svg#Lobster1.4') format('svg'),
         url('fonts/Lobster-1.4/Lobster-1.4.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/Lobster-1.4/Lobster-1.4.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

use:

```
.zone-text span {
    font-family: 'Lobster1.4';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: #3C3C3B;
}
```

looks like:
[image: dark text appear correctly]

with everything else same, just switching color to white it completely changes the font like it's a different typeface

like this:
[image: light text looks bolder]

Any idea why this could be or is it something I just have to live with.

//edit

with larger text (`3rem`) it's definitely still happening but I think it's more apparent as smaller sizes.

[image: larger dark text]

[image: larger light text]

Comment: Does the same thing happen at different sizes, or only when you use 1.3rem?

Comment: All similar sizes, I'll try something larger

Comment: Is this browser specific? Have you tried `-webkit-font-smoothing`

Comment: Provide your full @font-face declaration so we can dig more. Actually this looks more like a 'text-shadow' applied ..

Comment: Is it the same with a different background? It's probably because if the red

Comment: added-full font-face declaration, adding `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`  fixes it for Chrome, firefox is still too bold.

Comment: Is something browser/OS kind of deciding that it needs to provide extra readability so makes it bold.

Comment: No text shadow, looks like subpixel rendering crazyness. (I'm using a mac)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the red background:

<s>All</s> A lot of colors on red background:

http://bcn.boulder.co.us/community/tools/colors/sccscred.htm

And here you can have grades for you contrast:

http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html

You will notice *Contrast Ratio* is under 4.5 and *Colour Difference* is below 500.

Also *Brightness Difference* barely crosses 125 at 145.

Where black on white is:

> Contrast Ratio: 21 Colour Difference: 765 Brightness Difference: 255

Comment: THat's very useful to know, it seems, the effect can be reduced by using `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` on Chrome at least.